# Symfony - Default routing. Auto Mapping /{controller/{action}

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to map my url automatically to a controller.

> example.com/test | MyBundle:Default:Index
>
> example.com/test/login | MyBundle:Default:Login

That's my approach but it isn't working yet.
The thing is that the action should be optional and if not provided should default to "Index".

**app/config/routing.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

// load route collection object
$collection = new RouteCollection();

// add default route
$collection->add('default', new Route('/{_controller}/{_action}', array(
    '_controller' => 'MyBundle:Default:Index',
        ), array('_method' => 'GET')
        )
);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony uses in it's workflow an attribute called '_controller' in the Request-Object. At a certain point, the attribute is filled with something like

- MyBundle:Default:Index or
- project.bundle.controller:method (if you registered your controller as a service)

You can also use this attribute as parameter in your route:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

// load route collection object
$collection = new RouteCollection();

// add default route
$collection->add('default', new Route('/{_controller}'));
```

Then you can call http://example.com/MyBundle:Default:Index, which correctly resolves and executes the controller.

But please be sure, not to use this in a productional environment as this really is bad practice.

Comment: First of all: The URLs are ugly and not self-explaining. Second is you always need to add _controller as parameter while generating a route. If you change the name of the bundle, the controller or the method, you have to search for all occurrences in your code. If you miss one, you're code is definitely going to brake, without you knowing it. For getting started with symfony to try some stuff, it is just okay - but not for anything beyond that.